# Boolean "add" notation

Tags: notation, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I'm writing an academic paper and encountered the problem that what notations should I use for bit-wise Boolean addition, e.g.

$$\begin{array}{r}
0101 \\
+\ 0011 \\
\hline
0111
\end{array}$$

because for every bit $1+0=0+1=1+1=1$, and $0+0=0$.

If I use "$+$" it may be misunderstood as normal integer addition. But the notation "or" $\vee$ is used for one bit operation, e.g. $0\vee 1=1$.

So what noations should I use ?

Comment: In hardware, $|$ is used for bitwise or. As in $0101| 0011$ being $0111$.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

You may overload the $\vee$ operator for "bitwise or".

$0001\vee 0100 = 0101$

Comment: Thanks and that's a good idea.